# PK violation on cascade merge

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I'm facing an issue when trying to merge an entity which has a OneToMany relationship with another entity if the list is large enough, And by large enough I mean 300+ records.
Other systems I've worked with with the same infrastructure (Eclipselink, Weblogic 12c, Oracle Database 12c) can manage this without problem with much bigger lists, but in this particular scenario, I get a `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ADMALM.CNTGM_MAT_PK) violated ORA-06512: at line 1`. It looks as if multiple calls to the sequence's nextval return repeating numbers, but our DBA assured me that that's impossible.

---

Class A:

```
@Entity
public class Inventory {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "inventory", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })        
    private List<InventoryHistory> inventoryHistoryList;
}
```

Class B:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ALM_INVENTHIST", sequenceName = "SEQ_ALM_INVENTHIST", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class InventoryHistory {
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ID_INVENT")    
        private Inventory inventory;
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
   <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default"           value="false"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default"             value="0"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default"             value="None"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.id-validation"                  value="NULL"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" value="commit" />
</properties>
```

Comment: Is there a chance that elements in `inventoryHistoryList` are removed and added again? This might result in EclispeLink trying to delete the removed entities and persisting the new ones (even if it's basically the same) and this could cause the duplicate value if those operations happen in the wrong order.

Comment: You are using 'orphanRemoval = true', which will cause InventoryHistory to be marked for deletion if you dereference them in any Inventory - it isn't meant for references that might get moved from one owner to another. It is functionality built upon what was called private owned in TopLink/EclipseLink prior to JPA. You might get around it by forcing deletes to occur first (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Advanced_Unit_of_Work_API_%28ELUG%29#How_to_Use_the_setShouldPerformDeletesFirst_Method_of_the_Unit_of_Work) but it might be better to remove the orphanRemoval setting to avoid overhead.

Comment: I tried removing ```orphanRemoval = 'true'```, and the result is the same. The ```inventoryHistoryList``` was never populated before, so there's nothing to be deleted. Also, I should stress that the same code works perfectly with lists smaller than 300 records.

Comment: Show the code handling the collections then and and maybe we can tell what is happening. You might try running it on a DB with the constraint checking relaxed or delayed until the end of the transaction, with SQL logging enabled to see all the statements involved in the context/transaction, as that might give a clue to what it is trying to do and going wrong.